# how to verify if the elements in the list is alphabetically sorted or not

Tags: java, c#

```
I am using the following code to get the text values for employees from a web table and holding it in a list.Now i need to verify the employees stored in the list are in alphabetical order or not.

  int count = a.getobjectcount(//*[@id='GridTable']/tbody/tr[*]);
    List< String> list = new List<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
    a.getTextFromElement("//*[@id='emp_" +i+ "']");

    //Using for loop to get the number of employees and store it in a list

 list.add(element)// i am adding employees to the list here   
  }
```

Here i need to validate if employees is in alphabetical order or not something as boolean==true; if employees are in alphabetical order

Comment: Loop through the list, check each one against the next, if you find anything out of order, it's not alphabetical.  Think of it as one pass of a bubble sort, where instead of swapping elements you find out of order, you return false (or true if you get to the end with nothing out of place).

Answer (score 1):

Call this method:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> boolean isSorted(Iterable<E> coll) {
    E prev = null;
    for (E value : coll) {
        if (prev != null && prev.compareTo(value) > 0)
            return false;
        prev = value;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me for sorting validation

```
public Boolean validateSorting(){
int count = a.getobjectcount(//*[@id='GridTable']/tbody/tr[*]);
    List< String> list = new List<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
    a.getTextFromElement("//*[@id='emp_" +i+ "']");

    //Using for loop to get the number of employees and store it in a list

 list.add(element)// i am adding employees to the list here   
  }
 var y = list.First();
            return list.Skip(1).All(x =>
    {
       Boolean b = y.CompareTo(x) < 0;
        y = x;
        return b;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you are working with a List data structure, you can call the sort method from the Collections API.

```
// Sorts the list of employees
Collections.sort(list);
```